# Prove or disprove interior equality

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Prove or disprove the following statement:
$$Int(Bd(A)) = Int(Fr(A))$$

Where Bd(A): boundary of A and Fr(A): frontier of A

$FrA := \overline{A} \cap \overline{A'} $

$BrA := FrA \cap A = A \cap \overline{A'} $

$A'$ : complement of A

$\overline{A}$ : closure of A

To disprove it I took $A = [0,1)\ on\ \mathbb{R}$
Then $Bd(A) = \{0\}$ and $Fr(A) = \{0,1\} => Int(Bd(A)) = \{0\}  \ Int(Fr(A)) = \{0,1\}$

Since on $\mathbb{R}$  singletons are closed thus interiors wouldn't be empty sets. But I am not sure if this is right.

Comment: Can you define $\text{Bd}$ and $\text{Fr}$? Is $\text{Bd}$ supposed to be the boundary of $A$? Then what is $\text{Fr}$?

Comment: The interior of a set is the largest open set contained within the set. Thus the interior of a singleton is empty. Your counterexample is not valid.

Comment: @MeeSeongIm Fr is the frontier of A

Comment: In many books the frontier is another name for the boundary. Please give an explicit definition.

Comment: Your definition of $Fr A$ mkaes no sense, as $\overline{A} \cup \overline{A'} = \overline{A \cup A'}  = X$. You must mean $\overline{A} \cap \overline{A'}$ instead.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes you are right I miswrote it.

Comment: @RobertThingum correction: $FrA := \overline{A} \cap \overline{A'}$

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking note of Pumpkin's definitions wherein:

$$Fr(A):=\overline{A}\cap\overline{A^{\prime}}\text{ and }Bd(A):=Fr(A)\cap A$$

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{Q}$. Then $Fr(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{R}$ and $Bd(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Q}$. Thus:

$$int(Fr(\mathbb{Q}))=int(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}\text{ and }int(Bd(\mathbb{Q}))=int(\mathbb{Q})=\emptyset$$